# does this building feature a brise soleil?

Tags: building-design, architecture

Is the curtain wall glass facade on the building in the following picture a [brise soleil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brise_soleil)?

[image]

Comment: Do you think it is there to create shading?

Comment: is it positioned between the sun and the building?

Comment: opening that location in googleearth will probably show a 3d model and sun course can be tweaked to see if this is meant to be a sunshade. Other way is search info on architects website that built this. Difficult to answer with such few infos atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referenced Wikipedia page defines Brise Soleil (sun breaker) as "an architectural feature of a building that reduces heat gain within that building by deflecting sunlight".

Image is Block 185, in Austin, Texas (ironically a Google building).  [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/search/block+185,+austin/@30.26702921,-97.75225407,218.52148517a,605.31049591d,35y,-1.34290836h,88.02023491t,0r/data=CigiJgokCYU1yo_GRjxAEa0qrYalZi3AGVlSLhob3DvAIfNtDlqhhmHA) shows building oriented to south.  Wing shape is facing west-ish.  Note building is on top of Shoal Creek, west of the building.

[image]

From [austonia: Architect involved in Austin's new Google tower outlines considerations that led to unique design:](https://austonia.com/google-tower-austin-skyline)

> The previous land development code for the city required that any projects in that area up against a body of water like a creek, lake or river needed to have a slope down in the form of a 40-degree setback to preserve solar access.

> The design team also had to consider the Texas heat, which they handled with automatic shades plus solar sunscreens on the curved portion facing west.

The shape has more to do with allowing as much sun access to Shoal Creek (to west) and Lady Bird Lake (to south) as possible.  The sail is not a sun breaker and requires sunscreens on the sail and shades (with plants) on the south side of the building.